# Redhat EL 7.2 using postfix to use smtp.gmail.com to relay not working

Tags: linux, postfix, redhat, gmail, rhel7

I am running `rhel 7.2`, I have `postfix` installed and can't get it to relay through gmail smtp servers.  I have followed lots of tutorials and googled and tried answers to lots of others posts but I can't seem to get anything to work.

This is the current error I have in the `/var/log/maillog` (i replaced the hostname and email addresses with x for privacy:

```
Jun 30 16:35:15 xxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[31716]: 1DC08C13E1CA: from=<root@xxxxxxxxxx.localdomain >, size=277, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 30 16:35:15 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtp[31846]: 1DC08C13E1CA: to=<xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com>,  relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.193.109]:587, delay=3512, delays=3512/0.02/0.31/0.04, d sn=5.5.1, status=bounced (host smtp.gmail.com[173.194.193.109] said: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14 257 z205sm11773703itc.11 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Jun 30 16:35:15 inigo postfix/cleanup[31848]: 9544CC13E1CF: message-id=<2016063022351 5.9544CC13E1CF@inigo>
Jun 30 16:35:15 xxxxxxxx postfix/bounce[31847]: 1DC08C13E1CA: sender non-delivery notifi cation: 9544CC13E1CF
Jun 30 16:35:15 xxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[31716]: 9544CC13E1CF: from=<>, size=2283, nrcpt=1  (queue active)
Jun 30 16:35:15 inigo postfix/qmgr[31716]: 1DC08C13E1CA: removed
Jun 30 16:35:15 inigo postfix/smtp[31846]: 9544CC13E1CF: to=<root@xxxxxxxxxx.localdomain>,  relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.193.108]:587, delay=0.32, delays=0.01/0/0.28/0.03, dsn= 5.5.1, status=bounced (host smtp.gmail.com[173.194.193.108] said: 530-5.5.1 Authentic ation Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257  p131sm3141384itg.17 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Jun 30 16:35:15 xxxxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[31716]: 9544CC13E1CF: removed
```

I have tried multiple solutions from answers online and this is what my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file ended up looking like:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = xxxxxxxx
myorigin = $myhostname
inet_interfaces = 10.10.10.10,127.0.0.1
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.10.10.0/24
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
message_size_limit = 10485760
mailbox_size_limit = 1073741824
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_local_domain = $myhostdomain
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_auth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
smtp_tls_security_level = secure
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_secure-cert_match = nexthop
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
debug_peer=smtp.gmail.com
debug_peer_level=3`
```

by the way `postfix` is the owner of the `/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd` file

If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some help and they found that the passwd file didn't have brackets like the main.cf file did around the smtp.gmail.com so I changed that and remapped with postmap, then it gave me a different error that mentioned no worthy mechanism available, so I did a google search and found someone else had the same error and just installed cyrus-sasl-plain and that did the trick.  Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Thanks! This was it! I was breaking my head with what not.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have formatted `/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd` correctly.

It should appear as:

```
smtp.gmail.com     user@gmail.com:password_or_app_password
```

After setting this file, you need to run `postmap` on it, to update the hash.

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
```

Then reload postfix.

```
systemctl reload postfix
```

Comment: I removed the brackets around smtp.gmail.com and double and quadruple  checked the email and password, ran the postmap command and reloaded but still the same authentication error from gmail...thanks for your suggestion, any other ideas?